# Ubuntu with Nvidia drivers capped at 60 FPS on a 144hz screen (single monitor)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gnome, graphics, display

### The Problem

*All the systems specs can be found at the bottom.*

Ubuntu 20.04 with `nvidia-driver-*` is capped at 60 FPS on a 144hz screen. I'm aware this happens in a multi-screen setup with one screen being 60hz, but the problem persists even when there's only the primary 144hz screen in use.

**The problem goes away if I switch to the iGPU with `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` drivers.** Everything is butter smooth, as it should be. Yet when I switch back to dGPU and `nvidia-driver-*` drivers, the issue returns.

#### Some symptoms

1. For a brief period of time, the issue went away. This happened after one of the `nvidia-*` updates, though I can't say exactly which one. For a while, everything worked as it should, but after the next update, the issue returned. I believe it was the update from `455.38` to `455.45` that broke it again. Going back to the previous driver version (downgrading from `455.45` to `455.38`) did not help. I have also tried purging all the `nvidia` drivers and reinstalling them and using `nvidia-driver-450`.
2. The mouse cursor *can* be rendered at 144 FPS. By default it's also capped, but if I change the refresh rate in display settings back and forth, it temporarily becomes 144 FPS. It will reset back to 60 FPS after some time, and I'd have to change the setting back and forth again for it to resume being smooth.
3. `xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 144` did not help.

### System specs

```
System:
  Kernel: 5.4.0-58-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.4 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Schenker product: XMG FUSION 15 (XFU15L19) 
CPU:
  Model: Intel Core i7-9750H 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 630 driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
  Device-2: NVIDIA TU106M [GeForce RTX 2070 Mobile] vendor: Intel 
  driver: nvidia v: 455.45.01 bus ID: 01:00.0 
  Display: server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: modesetting,nvidia 
  unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~144Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: GeForce RTX 2070 with Max-Q Design/PCIe/SSE2 
  v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 455.45.01 direct render: Yes 
Info:
  Memory: 62.66 GiB
```

Answer (score 0):

In nvidia-settings, untick 'allow flipping''.

Comment: Might be, but could you elaborate why this might help the OP?

Answer (score 0):

I've met this problem too.
I guess it maybe vsync that make this issue
With vsync off in the terminal, the game (minecraft) reach the high flash rate, but the gnome desktop still capped at 60hz.

Comment: strangely in recovery mode it becomes smooth, maybe because it not call gpu?